# vim quickfix avoid buffer change

Tags: vim

I'm using `vimgrep` with `cw` to open the search results in the `quickfix` buffer. Every time I select a line in the quickFix list the cursor shifts to the new file buffer. How do I avoid this and keep my cursor in the quickFix list always?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using `<CR>` to "select a line in the quickFix list", you can simply remap `<CR>` *in the quickfix window* so that you come back to the previous window after jumping to the matching line.

Make sure you have `filetype plugin indent on` and add the line below to `~/.vim/ftplugin/qf.vim`:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <CR> <CR><C-w>p
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this by editing .vimrc instead of .vim/ftplugin/qf.vim?

Comment: @LorinHochstein `:autocmd FileType qf nnoremap <buffer> <CR> <CR><C-W>p`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:cnext` and `:cprevious` combined with a `<C-w>p` (focus on previous window).

To bind them to e.g. `<Leader>cn` and `<Leader>cp`, you could do:

```
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>cn :cnext<CR><C-w>p
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>cp :cprevious<CR><C-w>p
```